# Flickrapi giving a TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)

Tags: class, python-2.7, typeerror, flickr

I am going back and working through old coursework from my intro to comp sci class, and on one of the labs I'm supposed to use the flickrapi module to scrape flickr for a set of pictures to use for the rest of the lab. The project was assigned with some code to scrape flickr that I know should work, but whenever I run the code it throws a TypeError. The function that is returning an error is:

```
def getphotos(apicode, query, num_images):
''' Return a list of URLs that have a tag that 
    matches the query code. '''
# Form the object that will interact with the Flickr website
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(apicode,  format='etree')

# Get each matching photo and store in a list, stopping when we
# reach the target number of images
photos = []
for photo in flickr.walk(tags = query, tag_mode = 'all', safe_search = '0', sort = 'interestingness-desc'):
    url = "http://farm" + photo.get('farm') + ".staticflickr.com/" + \
        photo.get('server') + "/" + photo.get('id') + "_" + \
        photo.get('secret') + ".jpg"
    print url
    photos.append(url)
    if len(photos) >= num_images:
        break

return photos
```

The line that throws the error is  `flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(apicode,  format='etree')` where apicode represents an apicode key given to me by flickr and I'm not quite sure what the `format ='etree'` does. When I go look at the flickrapi module and go into core.py, I get to the FlickrAPI class. The part of the class that seems to be of interest is given as:

```
class FlickrAPI(object):
"""Encapsulates Flickr functionality.

Example usage::

  flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key)
  photos = flickr.photos_search(user_id='73509078@N00', per_page='10')
  sets = flickr.photosets_getList(user_id='73509078@N00')
"""

REST_URL = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/'
UPLOAD_URL = 'https://up.flickr.com/services/upload/'
REPLACE_URL = 'https://up.flickr.com/services/replace/'

def __init__(self, api_key, secret, username=None,
        token=None, format='etree', store_token=True,
        cache=False):
...(followed by logic statements involving the inputs for __init__ and class methods)
```

When flickr gives me an apicode key, it also gives me a secret key which I have stored in a .txt file in the same directory as the program I'm working on.

Now obviously the call on the FlickrAPI class is being passed 3 arguments, 2 of which are the apicode key and the format ='etree', but I'm a little bit unsure as to what the third one is. Is the class somehow calling on the secret key through flickr, or is it one of the other inputs for **init**? How do I got about fixing the type error that the code is giving me?

Answer (score 0):

The three required arguments are `self`, `api_key` and `secret` (arguments that have no default value), the example given in the docstring of the FlickrAPI does not work.

Here, the first argument, `self`, is implicit (it's the instance of the FlickrAPI being constructed itself), you are giving the second argument, `api_key`, with `apicode`, but the third required argument, `secret`, is missing. `format` is the third argument you give, but it doesn't count in the three required arguments, as it has a default value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't pass anything for `secret`.

Take a look at this example

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, one, two, three=3):
        print one, two, three

Test(1, three=3)
```

`Test.__init__` takes four arguments, of which one (`three`) has a default value, so it needs at least `self`, `one` and `two` passed to it. `self` is passed automatically because it is a class method, so that's the first. Then you pass something for `one` and something for `three`. You do pass three arguments, which is the minimum, but you pass nothing for `two`, which doesn't have any default value. That's where the error comes from. You could call `Test(1, 2)` which has the same number of arguments because then all arguments without a default value are provided.

In your code, you are passing an argument for `api_key` and an argument for `format`, but nothing for `secret`, which doesn't have a default value.